# Apply CSS for specific image only

Tags: html, css

I have this codepen, please view it.

https://codepen.io/gianlucaps/pen/GRvVjmZ

the problem is, when you view it you can see, is that the very first image, the huge big one, is way to big. I tried to size it down manually using my editor, but didn't work. So now I am trying to apply some css to only that image, for both the desktop and responsive versions. Please see this code below, that is what I tried to put in:

```
  <img data-image="red" class="active" src="https://res.cloudinary.com/piersolutions/image/upload/v1637872858/Rolex_for_Joseph-removebg-preview-3_ajtqtu.png" id="mainRolex">

 <style>
  #mainRolex {
    height: 50%;
    width: 30%;
    left: 22%;
    top: 10%;
  }
</style>
```

and it worked! But the problem is, when you go on mobile, it disappears. not to mention, when I do some fiddling around with it, it doesn't apply to the `left-column` section, but I'm not sure why! Can someone help me fix it for desktop and mobile?

Comment: percentage size is based on the size of the parent, that's why it can be unpredictable, try using another unit or fixing the parent's size

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't understand you well, so I decided to download your code and try it by myself to see more o less whats your problem so...

To the first problem of the big image, I recommend you using the css property `object-fit: scale-down` and it looks a bit better

The second, in my browser, I could see the image when put it in responsive, but it didn't look pretty well, so I add this styles

```
@media (max-width: 640px) {
    .container {
        flex-direction: column;
        margin-top: 60px;
    }

    .left-column{
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        left: 0;
        top: 40%;
    }
    .right-column {
        position: absolute;
        width: 50%;
        right: 0;
    }

    .left-column img {
        width: 80%;
        left: 0;
        top: -65px;
    }
}
```

And

```
@media (max-width: 535px) {
    .left-column img {
        width: 120px;
        top: 60%;
        left: -17px;
    }
    .right-column {
        position: absolute;
        width: min-content;
        right: 0;
        top: -50px;
    }
```

and I guess it looked like you wish.